# MVC: Ajax data not getting to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Every solution/similiar question has to do with json objects. I think the problem may be caused by using html. I have also verified the data is not empty before it hits the ajax call.

Here is the Ajax

```
function SubmitSearch() {
    var type = $("#select_SearchType").val()
    var query = $("#input_Search").val()

    $.ajax({
        //url: "newSearch",
        url: '@Url.Action("newSearch", "Results")',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        data: { type: type, query: query },
        success: function (ViewModel) {
            alert(ViewModel)
            $("#div_record").empty();
            $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
        },
        error: function (ViewModel) {
            alert("error")
            $("#div_record").empty();
            $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
        },
    });
}
```

And selected code from the Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult newSearch(string type, string query)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case " ":
                response.errMess = "empty data, T:" + type + " Q:" + query;
                return PartialView("Record", response);
            default:
                response.errMess = "Error: mismatched fields, T:" + type + " Q:" + query;
                return PartialView("Record", response);
        }
```

type and query both come in empty

Comment: Why is your `contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8'` when you're actually posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If you're expecting HTML in *response*, `dataType: 'html'` should suffice. `contentType` is used by the *request*.

Comment: I figured that would be correct since the type of objects I'm sending are just plain text strings

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8'`. There are some methods.

First, you have to use something like this (put parameters directly in `url`):

```
$.ajax({
    //url: "newSearch",
    url: '@Url.Action("newSearch", "Results")?type='+type+'&query='+query,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (ViewModel) {
        alert(ViewModel)
        $("#div_record").empty();
        $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
    },
    error: function (ViewModel) {
        alert("error")
        $("#div_record").empty();
        $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
    },
});
```

Second.
You have to save some data to the server using [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) property.

If you want to return `PartialView`, there is no need to use `dataType: "html"`

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    //url: "newSearch",
    url: '@Url.Action("newSearch", "Results")',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: { type: type, query: query },
    success: function (ViewModel) {
        alert(ViewModel)
        $("#div_record").empty();
        $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
    },
    error: function (ViewModel) {
        alert("error")
        $("#div_record").empty();
        $("#div_record").html(ViewModel)
    },
});
```

Comment: Since the action returns a `PartialView`, the OP is rightfully expecting HTML in return. Using `dataType: 'json'` will prevent that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks. I do not see that method return `partialView`.